# Combine two row values and pivot the row values into column headers

Tags: sql-server

Here is the source table that we are working with:

```
+-----------+-----------+------+----------+----------+  
| startdate | enddate   | Type | Planet   | Rotation |  
+-----------+-----------+------+----------+----------+  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | A1   | Netptune | P1       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | A2   | Netptune | P2       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | A3   | Netptune | P3       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | A4   | Netptune | P4       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | B1   | Saturn   | P1       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | B2   | Saturn   | P2       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | B3   | Saturn   | P3       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | B4   | Saturn   | P4       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | B5   | Saturn   | P5       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | C1   | Pluto    | P1       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | C2   | Pluto    | P2       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | C3   | Pluto    | P3       |  
| 4/4/2016  | 4/10/2016 | C4   | Pluto    | P4       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | D1   | Netptune | P1       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | D2   | Netptune | P2       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | D3   | Netptune | P3       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | D4   | Netptune | P4       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | E1   | Saturn   | P1       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | E2   | Saturn   | P2       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | E3   | Saturn   | P3       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | E4   | Saturn   | P4       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | E5   | Saturn   | P5       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | F1   | Pluto    | P1       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | F2   | Pluto    | P2       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | F3   | Pluto    | P3       |  
| 4/11/2016 | 4/17/2016 | F4   | Pluto    | P4       |  
+-----------+-----------+------+----------+----------+
```

The Pivot query I'm looking for will take the planet row value and add it to the value in the rotation column and make that a column header. Please see the picture below to see the output table.

Result from Pivot Query:

[image]

Comment: Sadly, Pluto is no longer considered a planet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [**dynamic crosstab**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @sql = 
'SELECT
      StartDate
    , EndDate' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN Planet = ''' + Planet + ''' AND Rotation = ''' +
         Rotation + ''' THEN Type END) AS ' + QUOTENAME(Planet + Rotation) + CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT DISTINCT Planet, Rotation FROM tbl
) t
ORDER BY Planet, Rotation

SELECT @sql = @sql +
'FROM tbl
GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate
ORDER BY  StartDate, EndDate;'
;

EXEC (@sql);
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/471918)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Its works! I couldn't figure it out! Very much appreciated!!!

Comment: Glad to have been of help! Feel free to accept my answer if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: Also, please read the article referenced in the answer. It will help you understand the query.

Comment: how do I accept your answer? sorry

Comment: @CiberLover007 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work